# Advice needed implementing direct and inverse Dijkstra algorithm in Scala/Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dijkstra

I'm trying to implement both **direct** Dijkstra and its **inverse** version (that is finding longest path instead of shortest ones) but I'm having some trouble because I'm getting infinite distances for not disconnected nodes in the weighted undirected graph (and zero distances in the inverse version).

So far, I trusted in and modified this implementation I found in web: [http://note.yuhc.me/2015/03/graphx-pregel-shortest-path/]

My implementations for both functions are as follows:

Direct Dijkstra:

```
// Implementation of Dijkstra algorithm using Pregel API
def computeMinDistance(u: VertexId, k1: VertexId): Double = {

  val g: Graph[(Double, VertexId), Double] = this.uncertainGraph.mapVertices((id, _) =>
    if (id == u) (0.0, id) else (Double.PositiveInfinity, id)
  )

  println("Computing Digkstra distance info fof id: " + u.toString)

  val sssp: Graph[(Double, VertexId), Double] = g.pregel[(Double, VertexId)]((Double.PositiveInfinity, Long.MaxValue), Int.MaxValue, EdgeDirection.Either)(
    (id, dist, newDist) => {
      if(dist._1 < newDist._1) {
        (dist._1, id)
      } else {
        (newDist._1, id)
      }
    },
    triplet => {  // Send Message
      if (triplet.srcAttr._1 + triplet.attr < triplet.dstAttr._1) {

        println("triplet.srcAttr._1 = " + triplet.srcAttr._1 .toString)
        println("triplet.dstAttr._1 = " + triplet.dstAttr._1 .toString)

        Iterator((triplet.dstId, (triplet.srcAttr._1 + triplet.attr, triplet.srcId)))
      } else {
        Iterator.empty
      }
    },
    (a, b) => (math.min(a._1, b._1), a._2) // Merge Message
  )

  sssp.vertices.take(20).foreach(println(_))

  sssp.vertices.filter(element => element._1 == k1).map(element => element._2._1).collect()(0)

}
```

Inverse Dijkstra:

```
def computeMaxDistance(node: VertexId, center: VertexId): Double = {

val g: Graph[(Double, VertexId), Double] = this.uncertainGraph.mapVertices((id, _) =>
  if (id != node) (0.0, id) else (Double.PositiveInfinity, id)
)

val sslp: Graph[(Double, VertexId), Double] = g.pregel[(Double, VertexId)]((Double.PositiveInfinity, Long.MaxValue), Int.MaxValue, EdgeDirection.Either)(
  (id, dist, newDist) => {
    if(dist._1 > newDist._1) {
      (dist._1, id)
    } else {
      (newDist._1, id)
    }
  },
  triplet => {  // Send Message
    if (triplet.srcAttr._1 + triplet.attr > triplet.dstAttr._1) {

      println("triplet.srcAttr._1 = " + triplet.srcAttr._1 .toString)
      println("triplet.dstAttr._1 = " + triplet.dstAttr._1 .toString)

      Iterator((triplet.dstId, (triplet.srcAttr._1 + triplet.attr, triplet.srcId)))
    } else {
      Iterator.empty
    }
  },
  (a, b) => (math.max(a._1, b._1), a._2) // Merge Message
)

sslp.vertices.take(20).foreach(println(_))

sslp.vertices.filter(element => element._1 == center).map(element => element._2._1).collect()(0)
```

}

Any help deeply appreciated. I'm not really that experienced with Scala and Spark. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're much more likely to get an answer with a complete working example.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. Would you mind explaining what do u mean by "complete working example" ? I would surely do it if it is necessary.

Comment: What SO calls an [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Personally if I can't copy and paste the code in a Scala question into a REPL and have it compile (or see a relevant compilation error), there's a 99% chance I'm closing the tab.

Comment: Please, leave it open. Someone will give advice despite not meeting your standards . Thank you very much. And, please, don't take me wrong.

Comment: [There is no known inverse Dijkstra's algorithm, and the longest path problem is NP-hard](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/17980/is-it-possible-to-modify-dijkstra-algorithm-in-order-to-get-the-longest-path).

Comment: It seems like you have two problems here (direct and inverse). Could please [edit] your question so that it only asks about one problem, then ask another question for the other? This makes it easier for people to answer if they only have a solution to one problem; otherwise, they might not answer. See [ask].

Comment: Well, thanks for spending your time to review Brian. I'm not really a graph-theoritic guy, but an ex-teacher of mine would propose as an exercise to compute longest path by inverting the logic of Dijkstra algorithm. Anyway, nobody is infallible. 
What about inverting Dijkstra algorithm for finding a good greedy approximation ? They use the term "longish" in the link you provided. Maybe I should re-post on SE. As I mentioned, graph is undirected. Does it make any difference ? It is a real-world PPI graph, presumably scale-free. Judging by your answer I will edit or have it drop it. Thanks.

Comment: I did direct algorithm in Scala, based on Princeton University Algorithms Course, not sure if this may help you: https://medium.com/se-notes-by-alexey-novakov/algorithms-in-scala-dijkstra-shortest-path-78c4291dd8ab